# Ruby parser for scripting

Tags: python, parser, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to edit Ruby files using Python scripts and I need to

1. Check if a function call exists within a class, add if not present, check function call args if present and change accordingly
2. Check if a function def exists and if not insert a function definition inside a class
3. Points 1 and 2 for blocks (and also for classes and modules)
4. When rebuilding the edited file comments should be intact

Suggest me a Ruby/Rails parser written in Python. Also, tell me if it is a lot easier in Ruby itself rather than finding a library in Python, and if that would give me a lot more flexibility and even more abilities to control the Ruby files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to edit the ruby files while the ruby application is running?
Or are you using the python scripts to generate a project, like [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter)?

Ruby does support reflection and metaprogramming so you can:

1. check if a method exists using [respond_to?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F)
2. define a method using [define_method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method).

If it were me, I'd do everything in ruby, but it depends on your usecase.

Comment: I am trying to generate a project just like cookiecutter. And you are right, I later realized I will have to end up having a full fledge ruby parser in one way or the other written wholly in Python, and it makes more sense to use Ruby's own reflection and meta api to change things in ruby files for checking if the function exists or not, or to add new ones. But it would still fall short when it comes to adding an assignment statement and function calls in an existing function or blocks. (Or would it? do we have methods for that as well?)